# What would cause config export (drush cex) to output to multiple folders instead of just config/sync?

Tags: configuration

settings.php has a single config sync setting:

```
$settings['config_sync_directory'] = '../config/sync';
```

Yet every time we run "drush cex" it writes the same config .yml files to three places:

/config
/config/sync
/config/sync/sync

This is baffling! I have many sites using config sync and cannot figure out why we are getting this odd behaviour.

[image]

Comment: Does the site have https://www.drupal.org/project/config_split?

Comment: Yeah, thought of config split as well. And can you maybe search the whole config dir for a string like `config/` or `/sync`?

Comment: I wish it was that simple. Config Split is not installed. I triple-checked to be sure. The only config related module installed is Config Ignore.

Comment: Check if $settings['config_sync_directory'] is set multiple times across different settings file like settings.php, settings.local.php etc. More importantly check if declaring an absolute path like 'sites/default/sync' makes a difference as opposed to a relative path